# G++ and sed pipeline

Tags: bash, sed, g++

I would like to replace all "no" by "on" in the console output of g++. I tried

```
$ g++ | sed -e 's/no/on/g'
```

But it shows

> i686-apple-darwin9-g++-4.0.1: **no** input files

instead of

> i686-apple-darwin9-g++-4.0.1: **on** input files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message is arriving on the standard error, but the shell pipe operator connects the standard output of one process to the standard input of the next.

To reroute stderr, use

```
$ g++ 2>&1 | sed -e 's/no/on/g'
```

or

```
$ g++ |& sed -e 's/no/on/g'
```

to get

```
g++: on input files
```

Comment: Wow, 59 secs... Thank you! I did not know how to redirect error stream to standard stream.

Comment: `|&` is new in Bash 4.0, although it has been in other shells (like zsh) for much longer.